# Is it possible to send an anonymous invite from a facebook app to a facebook user?

Tags: facebook, api

I am developing an app that requires to send an anonymous invite to another user to use the application. If that is not possible, is it possible to send a message to another user as the application?

Comment: Nope, and nope. (Imagine the spamming possibilities of that – who was the user to report for spamming if there is not even a clear sender of a message?)

Comment: Well, the thing is that i would like to be a product of a user interaction, but my application requires to do this without the name of the user appearing in the request. I guess it's not possible then. Thanks for the reply!